# How to fix sass error when trying to knit R Markdown files?

Tags: sass, r-markdown, knitr, bslib

I am struggling to get R Markdown to work in terms of knitting files. The error I am getting seems to be related to sass. However, even after installing the package associated with sass, it's still throwing error messages.

Has anyone had this issue before?

- [sass error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueOBp.png)
- [console with sass installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE6TG.png)

I tried `install.packages('rmarkdown')` again, and I also checked that the package is in my package library in RStudio. I also tried `install.packages("bslib", dependencies = TRUE)` as I read online this package contains sass - my console said "package 'sass' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked" but my file still won't knit. I am also not getting the correct formatting usually associated with RMarkdown.